# Adding Custom Merge Tags in Mailchimp API 3.0

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I have get around everywhere, but cannot find any clue to add custom merge tags through the api v3.0. The documentation seems to be very poor and cryptic.

I saw that in the previous version, it can be done through `listMergeVarAdd()` method.

What I want to do is adding any `merge_tags` dynamically.

How do I can add custom `merge_tags` through mailchimp api 3.0 for the use in a custom subscribe form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since v3.0 is RESTful, you make a `POST` call to the `/3.0/lists/{list_id}/merge-fields` endpoint. The data you pass should match the [List Merge Field Instance schema](https://us9.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Lists/MergeFields/Instance.json).

Comment: Did you mean it will automatically create any custom `merge_tags` I pass to it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. This is pretty standard REST behavior. A list's collection of merge fields lives at `/3.0/lists/{list_id}/merge-fields`, and the way you add a new field to that collection is via POST to that endpoint.

Comment: I am sorry, I mean may I see an example?

Comment: this only allows creating a Merge Tag right?  What about setting the DATA for the Merge Tag?

Comment: @MikeW: Pass it through the `merge_fields` field on the member object. [Docs here](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#edit-patch_lists_list_id_members_subscriber_hash)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example after some researches, may be someone will find it useful.

This is using VATPS Wrapper available here https://github.com/vatps/mailchimp-rest-api

```
$api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-usx";      
$mc = new MailChimp();
$mc->setApiKey($api_key);

    // Create Custom Merge Tags - Example           
    $result = $mc->post('/lists/{list-id}/merge-fields', array(
                    "tag" => "CUSTOM_SST",
                    "required" => false, // or true to set is as required 
                    "name" => "Custom Field",
                    "type" => "text", // text, number, address, phone, email, date, url, imageurl, radio, dropdown, checkboxes, birthday, zip
                    "default_value" => "", // anything
                    "public" => true, // or false to set it as not 
                    "display_order" => 2,
                    "help_text" => "I try to help you!"
                ));
    print_r($result);

    // Check If Merge Tags Already Exists - Example
    $result = $mc->get('/lists/{list_id}/merge-fields');
    print_r($result);
```